# curve fit using scipy optimize

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
  x=np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
  df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/SHYAMA/Downloads/data2.csv')
  f=list(df['x0'])
  s=list(df['x1'])
  plt.figure(dpi=100)
  plt.plot(f,s)
  def func(x,a,b,c,d):
     return a*np.cos(b*x+c)+d
  param,error=curve_fit(func,f,s)
  plt.plot(x,func(x,*param))
  plt.grid()
  print(param,error)
```

I tried many methods , but I am getting the values very far away from expected values and the curve is not fitting properly.[curve is not properly fitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KshOe.jpg)

My question is what is the mistake and why scipy.optimize  not able to fit the curve properly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Give it some proper initial parameter guesses (additional argument of `curve_fit`). See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Comment: @mcsoini I tried giving the limits for the parameters.....but only if the limit is very narrow....the program is returning the proper values. For this simple curve fit, the program should normally give results without any additional data

Comment: In a non-linear fit like this, startingvalues do not have to be far off to get stuck in a local minimum. you can make automated guesses for the initia values, like min/max vales for amplitude and offset, or fourier transforms for frequency. There are also linear approaches using the integro-differential properties of the function in question.

Comment: ....found the link https://www.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales usuall provided by JJaquelin, user:6819132

Comment: @syamadas "I tried giving the limits for the parameters.....but only if the limit is very narrow....the program is returning the proper values" => that's exactly how this works. mikuszefski is giving some great suggestions